# Phabricator Development Guide to customize the logic

Tags: php, phabricator

I need to customize few logic in the Phabricator tool. But I couldn't able to find where the logic, MySql queries and view files are located.

Does it have any MVC folder structure like codeigniter or any other specific pattern?

Can anyone please help me to understand this or please share any links to understand the coding structure and customize the logic.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Phabricator documentation would the first point of start:

1. [Example of Extension for Phabricator](https://secure.phabricator.com/w/community_resources/)
2. [Adding a new class](https://secure.phabricator.com/book/phabcontrib/article/adding_new_classes/)

Most of them add new features to Phabricator functionality. The problem with changes is that you should maintain them, (use patch) to add them after every update.

Comment: So you mean it's not possible to edit/modify the existing functionality we can only create a new feature... even to create new feature the framework has its own structure where as no any documents available for it. Because I can't use my style of coding I should only use their framework structure to develop... Is there any provision for that?

Comment: It is possible to do that, as some of these extensions do. I would discourage you from making big changes in the logic, this make updating your application much harder. [This page](https://secure.phabricator.com/book/phabcontrib/) has enough information for the start.